# Create ChatterMessage programatically?

Tags: chatter, chatter-conversation

I want to use Chatter to notify somebody of a particular even via code, but you can't create ChatterConversation objects via DML.

Is there a good way to do this other than by hooking into the Chatter API? I can post to the user record feed, but then that would just add to the amount of 'noise' in the system from the POV of people who follow that user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked through the chatter documentation and it seems even the new Connect API doesn't have this feature.

The only option seems to be the Rest APIs 'POST /chatter/users/me/messages/' operation?